# How to get a form to pop-up using Jquery/Ajax in Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a button on a webpage that I would like to have a form pop up when clicked. The problem is, I have no idea how to pass information for html with ajax. I can successfully pass database information with ajax like so:

**View:**

```
def ajax_shipping(request):
    id_quote = request.GET.get('quote', None)
    quote = HomeTable.objects.filter(id=id_quote).values_list('quote_num_id', flat=True)
    items = ItemDetails.objects.filter(quote_num_id=quote).values_list('item', 'quan', 'shipped')
    detail_list = []
    for x in items:
        detail_list.append(x)
    data = {
        'item': detail_list
        }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**JQuery and Ajax:**

```
$("#id_iden").on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val() !== ""){
      var qn = $(this).val()
      $.ajax({
        url: "/ship/ajax-shipping/",
        data: { 'quote': qn },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          if (data.item[0]){
            $('#id_item1').val(data.item[0][0])
            $('#id_quan1').val(data.item[0][1])
            $('#id_ship1').val(data.item[0][2])
            var bo = (data.item[0][1]) - (data.item[0][2])
            $('#id_bo1').val(bo)
          }
        }
     })
   }
})
```

However, I have no idea how to send form and html information while making it popup. I am looking for a tutorial or some guidance so I can achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't completely understand what you want, but if you want to setup the popup form based on input from source window you should take a look on [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp).

Comment: That's the idea, but I am wondering if it is possible to do with Ajax becuase I will need to send database information to it

Comment: @Evan you need to send info from database to form or the other way around?

Comment: @doru I need to send form and html information to Ajax, if that makes sense

Comment: @Evan I suppose you want to send info using AJAX  to the django view. You don't need ajax to pop up a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should use a modal and the easiest way is to use the bootstrap framework which includes a modal plugin.
2. Probably you want something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal2&stacked=h). You have a button on the page which, when clicked ,pops up a modal and in the modal you have a form and another button which, when clicked, sends the form data using AJAX to the handler view.
3. To *send* data to your view you have to use the `post` method in your AJAX code and when you use `post` you have to send a `crsftoken` for django to validate the form.

Let's say you have the url to use with ajax `/ajax/send-data-through-ajax/` and your form submit button has a class `send-data` and two input fields with classes `name-data` and `pass-data` than you can send this data through AJAX like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // AJAX POST
    $('.send-data').click(function(){
      console.log('am i called');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/send-data-through-ajax/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "name": $(".name-data").val(),"password": $(".pass-data").val() },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });

    });


    // CSRF code
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        var i = 0;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (i; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    }); 


});
```

and in your **view.py** file:

```
import json
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse

def ajax_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
        data = {'message': "{} added".format(request.POST.get('name'))}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

You have to add ajax url to your **urls.py** file

```
url(r'^ajax/send-data-through-ajax/$', views.ajax_data, name = 'ajax-data')
```

More info on using django and AJAX you can find here:

1. [Basic Ajax](https://godjango.com/18-basic-ajax/)
2. [Django by Example](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/django-example)
3. [Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/django-javascript-integration-ajax-and-jquery)